# What arguments does the sizeof operator take in C?

Tags: c, parameters, pointers, arguments, sizeof

[*Original title referred to 'sizeof function'.*]

I tried these and they all worked:

```
char *p;

printf("Size of *p is %d\n",sizeof(*p));  //result =1
printf("Size of  p is %d\n",sizeof( p));  //result =4
printf("Size of  p is %d\n",sizeof(&p));  //result =4
```

I wonder why the first printf is 1, the 2nd and 3rd is 4?
So what arguments can sizeof can actually take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes a type.

`sizeof(char)` is always one. The variable `p` itself is a pointer, and on your platform that has a size of 4. Then you do `&p`, or a pointer to a pointer, which also has a size of 4.

On most modern desktop systems, a 32-bit architecture will have 4 byte pointers, while a 64-bit architecture will have 8 byte pointers.

`sizeof` itself is a keyword, resolved at compile-time, not a function. In C99, arrays can be variable length, and sizeof will wait until run-time to resolve this size.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the parenthesis are required when its operand is a type name.

Comment: You didn't fix it - you should say 'sizeof(char) is always one'.  You can also pass variables to sizeof (and then you don't need the parentheses).  In most contexts, sizeof() generates a compile-time constant; the exception is a C99 VLA - variable-length array, which means sizeof(arrayname) must be evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

`sizeof` isn't a function, it's a keyword. You could drop the parentheses and it would work just fine. Because it's not a function, it works with any type or object that you give it - it's much more flexible than a function.

Comment: its good info, but I dont think that´s what he was looking for

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it's (usually) a compile-time operator.  In C99, sizeof can be used at runtime to determine the size of a dynamically allocated array.  And there is one situation where it's
not allowed: expressions of "function" type (e.g. "sizeof (main)").

Comment: @Tom: Maybe not, but the question wasn't very clear. I hope they find this helpful nevertheless.

Comment: You can only drop the parentheses if you are taking the sizeof a value. If you are doing `sizeof(type)`, then you must have the parentheses.

Comment: That's because one of the valid operands for sizeof is a "parenthesized type-id" (the other being an object expression). So technically, you're applying sizeof to `(type)`, not to `type`. Really that's a distinction without a difference, but `sizeof *p` isn't "dropping the parentheses" any more that `1 + 2` is "dropping the parentheses" from `(1) + (2)`. Unlike function calls, operators just don't need parentheses.

Comment: If you give sizeof(SomeType), you must use the parentheses.  Since you can use parentheses with variables, I simply use 'sizeof(whatever)' always using parentheses; this infuriated a colleague who was adamant that it was crucial to distinguish between the variable and type usages - a distinction I still find to be without value.

Answer (score 8):

`sizeof` is not a function; it's an operator. It can be used in two ways: as `sizeof(typename)` and as `sizeof expression`. The parentheses are required when used with a type name. Parentheses are not needed when the operand is an expression, though for clarity's sake many programmers will parenthesize the expression regardless. Note that unlike most programming languages operators, `sizeof expression` does *not* evaluate its argument under normal circumstances, i.e., when its operand is not a C99 variable-length array.

Comment: Technically, it's used in two ways: `sizeof(typename)` and `sizeof expression`. Of course, any expression can be surrounded with parentheses if you feel like it, and it's often wise to do so since nobody ever remembers the precedence of sizeof. `sizeof (a) ? 1 : 2`, is 1, as is `sizeof a ? 1 : 2`, whereas `sizeof (a ? 1 : 2)` is `sizeof int`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in the most recent specification of C language - C99 - 'sizeof's argument can be evaluated. It is evaluated when 'sizeof' is used with variable-length arrays (VLAs).

Comment: @AndreyT: you are right that sizeof() may be evaluated at runtime, but the argument is still not evaluated - just the size of the argument.  This matters with 'sizeof(1/0.0)'; the expression is a double value - and because it is not evaluated, there is no exception. Fortunately, you can't divide an array, so the VLA part doesn't come into this discussion.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to clarify the parentheses issue and address C99 VLAs. Thanks folks!

Comment: Well, it all depends on the specific meaning of the term "evaluated". Note, that C99 itself in 6.5.3.4/2 explicitly states that in case of VLA the argument of 'sizeof' is evaluated:
"[...]If the type of the operand is a variable length array
type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated[...]"

Answer (score 2):

Becuase you are working on 32bit machine.

```
*p is a character == 1 byte.
p  is a pointer   == 4 bytes.
&p is an address of a pointer == 4 bytes. Same as char**
```

Answer (score 1):

Also note:

```
sizeof 'a' == 1   // C++
```

but

```
sizeof 'a' == 4   /* C */
```

(To be precise, sizeof 'a' == sizeof(int) in C as posted by pmg).

In C, the 'a' gets promoted to an int before it is evaulated.  One of the few incompatibilities between the two languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof (char)   = 1
sizeof (void *) = 4
```

The first one is 1 because you are passing a char. (p points to a char)
2nd and 3rd calls receive a char* / void* object, so they yield 4.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is saying that a char is 1 byte. (derefing your pointer to a the actual char data)

The second is saying that the pointer value is a 4 byte value, that is the memory location is represented by a 4 byte value.

The third is saying that the address of the pointer is a 4 byte value.

Size of can take all of those arguments, and it is reporting accurate response for all of the values.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other replies, beware of the possible terminological mixup.

In C world, 'byte' is the same as 'char'. I.e. each 'char' is 1 'byte' by definition. This meaning of 'byte' is not necessarily connected to the machine 'byte' in the underlying hardware. A C 'byte' (i.e. 'char') can consist of several machine 'bytes'. However, in C program you have no access to machine bytes. Everything is measured in C 'bytes' (i.e. in 'chars') and 'sizeof' gives your the size measured in 'chars'.

For these reasons, 'sizeof(char)' is always 1 regardless of how many machine bytes each 'char' actually consists of.

Comment: That said, a C implementation in which char was bigger than the smallest addressable unit of memory on the architecture would be very unsporting, since it would limit your options for low-level programming on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

The operand of the `sizeof` operator is a type.

If you use sizeof with an object or a value, its type is used instead.

```
sizeof 65; /* same as `sizeof (int);` */
sizeof 'X'; /* same as `sizeof (int);` */
sizeof 42.0; /* same as `sizeof (double);` */
float f;
sizeof f; /* same as `sizeof (float);` */
/* etc ... */
```

You can specify a type directly to the sizeof operator (as in the "same as" above). The parenthesis are needed *"to cast the operand to the right type"* (as in `(int)2.5`), not as syntax for `sizeof` itself

```
#include <math.h>
sizeof (12 * log(100)); /* same as `sizeof (double);` */
                        /* without the parenthesis, this would be */
                        /* (sizeof 12) * log(100); */
```

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof` operator shows the size of the data type we used.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;
    double d;
    printf("%d",sizeof(a));
    printf("%d",sizeof(b));
    printf("%d",sizeof(c));
    printf("%d",sizeof(d));
}
```

Output:

```
a = 4
b = 4
c = 1 
d = 8
```

If you are using 8 bit compiler.