# evaluation of operand in sizeof operator

Tags: c, sizeof

As sizeof operator evaluates operand if it's a VLA so I tried to test it as :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int sz=20,i=0,j=0;
  int arr[sz];
  printf("%d\n",sizeof((++i,sz)));
  printf("%d\n",sizeof((++j,arr)));
  printf("%d\n%d\n",i,j); 
}
```

I thought that i won't increment as sz is not VLA but j would increment as arr is VLA.
But in the output, none of the i and j incremented.

Comment: This is a question about C, not C++.  VLAs do not exist in C++.

Comment: Oh, somebody else tagged this as C++.  Bad somebody else.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207732/sizeof-behaving-unexpectedly/2208224#2208224):

> The "conversion" is due to the subtraction operator. You can see a similar, and perhaps more surprising, result with the comma operator:
>
> ```
> printf("%zu\n", sizeof(1, a));
> ```
>
> will also print `sizeof(int *)`, because of the comma operator resulting in a getting used in a value context.

Basically, due to the comma operator, [the type of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035066/type-of-an-array/2035255#2035255) `arr` is a pointer, and the size of the VLA doesn't come into the picture.  See my linked answer for details.

Comment: Ok..I understand..So is there a way that I can utilize this fact "sizeof evaluates operand if it is a vLA" to increment or modify some other operand as I was trying to do here ?

Comment: @Happy: I wouldn't call that "utilize", it's more like "abusing the `sizeof` operator".  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Not much of an explanation but I suspect it's some compiler optimization for the comma operator.  The value of a comma operation is the value of the last expression.  With the compiler knowing sizeof is a unary operator and presented with a comma operation, it doesn't bother to evaluate any but the last expression (regardless whether the last was a reference to a VLA or not).

I wrote some test programs (gcc 4.3.3 on Ubuntu 9.04):

> $ cat test.c # with sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    printf("%d\n",
            sizeof( printf("%s%d\n", "comma!", ++x), x));
}
```

> $ gcc -S test.c
>
> $ cat test.s

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .section    .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "%d\n"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx
        andl    $-16, %esp
        pushl   -4(%ecx)
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %ecx
        subl    $36, %esp
        movl    $0, -8(%ebp)
        movl    $4, 4(%esp)
        movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
        call    printf
        addl    $36, %esp
        popl    %ecx
        popl    %ebp
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Note the absences of the string literals and the second `printf()` call.

> $ cat test-alt.c # without sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    printf("%d\n",
                  ( printf("%s%d\n", "comma!", ++x), x));
}
```

> $ gcc -S test-alt.c
>
> $ cat test-alt.s

```
        .file   "test-alt.c"
        .section    .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "comma!"
.LC1:
        .string "%s%d\n"
.LC2:
        .string "%d\n"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx
        andl    $-16, %esp
        pushl   -4(%ecx)
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %ecx
        subl    $36, %esp
        movl    $0, -8(%ebp)
        addl    $1, -8(%ebp)
        movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
        movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
        movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
        call    printf
        movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    $.LC2, (%esp)
        call    printf
        addl    $36, %esp
        popl    %ecx
        popl    %ebp
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

It may be documented somewhere but I wouldn't know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof evaluates at compile time. In C99 for variable length arrays it will wait until runtime. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557362/what-arguments-does-the-sizeof-operator-take-in-c) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler knows the array size: it is obviously 20. I don't think that sz is VLA. Try to use use array size as function parameter, for eaxmple:

```
void Function(int size)
{
    int arr[size];
    ...
}
```

BTW, to understand what happens, it is recommended to read Assembly code produced by compiler. Check whether sizeof is replaced by a constant already at compile time.

Comment: The compiler does know the array size in this case, but it is techincally a VLA because sz is a variable, not a constant.  Even if it were a constant (const int sz=20;), that doesn't make the array any less a VLA (for all that it will always have the same size).